# timeout error in executing a linq query

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-ce

```
 IQueryable<MailHeader> mailHeader = 
     _ctx.MailHeaders.Where(w => (w.ToReceipientID.Contains(curUser) 
                                    || w.CCReceipientID.Contains(curUser) 
                                    || w.BCCReceipientID.Contains(curUser)) 
                                  && w.UnRead == true && w.IsDraft == false 
                                  && w.IsInbox == true 
                                  && (w.IsApproved == true || w.IsApproved == null));

int unReadMails = mailHeader.Count();
```

Hi everyone. Logging in for first time when I faced this issue.

While executing the above lines of my C# controller code I was getting time out expression. After looking at previous suggestions I tried making the query IQueryable and execute but still seeing timeout error while executing the count statment. Can anyone help to find the reason?

Comment: may be you can try to increase the time out in the DataContext. I am assuming _ctx is your DataContext.

Comment: Have you attempted to look at the SQL this is generating and run that against your SQL server to see if the query itself is bad? It could be you need to add some indexes to your table.

Comment: How many records are in the MailHeaders database table?  And, is that a normal table, or a view, or something else?  This will help identify whether the timeout is really a timeout, or might be something else (such as a deadlock, or a database view paging problem, etc).

Comment: @RyanTernier The query is working fine in SQL server and takes hardly a sec and gives me results.

Comment: @MattJordan its a normal table. Mailheader has around 300 rows.

Answer (score 1):

Your table is too small to cause a real timeout, so, this is most likely a deadlock that is broken only when the operation times out.

Since the LINQ query in your code creates an IQueryable<> object (like a pending query that may be run when needed), the .Count() is probably being called before the query actually runs, although I am not sure why this would be.

Test this by adding .ToList() to your query to force the query to run
(docs on IEnumerable<>.ToList() are here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
IEnumerable<MailHeader> mailHeader = 
     _ctx.MailHeaders.Where(w => (w.ToReceipientID.Contains(curUser) 
              || w.CCReceipientID.Contains(curUser) 
              || w.BCCReceipientID.Contains(curUser)) 
              && w.UnRead == true && w.IsDraft == false 
              && w.IsInbox == true 
              && (w.IsApproved == true || w.IsApproved == null)).ToList();

int unReadMails = mailHeader.Count();
```

If this does not time out, then the cause was a deadlock between the .Count() and the actual query.  If this still times out, then something else is locking the table and preventing the LINQ request from completing.

Comment: the code worked fine  after placing the code in the beginning of the method that is above other table operations being done in the same methof